# Is the Gamma function defined by $\int_{0}^\infty e^{-t}t^{z-1}\,\,dt?$

Tags: notation, gamma-function

Should you write 
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(z) := \int_{0}^\infty e^{-t}t^{z-1}\,\,dt, \text{ for } \Re(z) > 0, \tag{1}
\end{equation}
or 
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(z) = \int_{0}^\infty e^{-t}t^{z-1}\,\,dt, \text{ for } \Re(z) > 0?\tag{2}
\end{equation}

I thought that $\Gamma(z)$ is defined by the integral $$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-t}t^{z-1}\,\,dt,$$

So $(1)$ is the correct way to introduce the Gamma function in a paper?

Are these differences important when writing a mathematical paper, or subjective and down to personal preference?

Comment: It‘s down to personal preference and depends on the context.

Comment: That integral is the most common definition of the Gamma function, but not the only one, e.g. some may prefer Euler's [infinite product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Alternative_definitions).

Comment: @Kezer Okay cool, thanks.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Okay, makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is subjective.

My take is that if you are just reminding the reader of what your notation is, in conjunction with several other well-known facts, the $=$ sign is right. If you are, however, trying to make some subtle  point that hangs  on what is a definition and what is merely a fact, then the $:=$ is justified.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.